# Force devtools::install_github to install only 32-bit versions of packages?

Tags: r, package, 32bit-64bit, devtools

> **Goal**: I want to install [`dssrip`](https://github.com/eheisman/dssrip) package for R 3.6.0 32-bit on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I have both 32- and 64-bit versions of R 3.6.0 installed. In RStudio (1.2.1522), I set the default version to 32-bit then create new project with `packrat` enable. I included the following lines in the `.Rprofile` file inside project folder.

```
#### -- Packrat Autoloader (version 0.5.0) -- ####
source("packrat/init.R")
#### -- End Packrat Autoloader -- ####

dir.create("packages", recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
.libPaths("./packages")
message("Using library: ", .libPaths()[1])

options(dss_jre_location="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HEC\\HEC-DSSVue\\java")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HEC\\HEC-DSSVue\\java")
```

**Installation**:

```
install.packages(c("devtools", "rJava", "plyr", "reshape2", "stringr", "tidyverse"),
                 dependencies = TRUE)
library(rJava)
devtools::install_github("eheisman/DSS-Rip",
                         args = "--no-multiarch")
```

**Error**:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user007/Documents/ttn/R/Projects/dssrip/packages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'dssrip' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Note: possible error in 'month(d, label = TRUE, ': unused arguments (label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE) 
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'dssrip'
    finding HTML links ... done
    AF_PER_CFS_DAY                          html  
    dss_path_functions                      html  
    fixTimestamps                           html  
    getColumnsByName                        html  
    getDT                                   html  
    getFullDT                               html  
    getFullTSC                              html  
    getLooseTSC                             html  
    getMetadata                             html  
    getTSC                                  html  
    hydro_axis_trans                        html  
    hydrologic_date_functions               html  
    initialize.dssrip                       html  
    model_error_measurement                 html  
    nash.sutcliffe                          html  
    opendss                                 html  
    rmse                                    html  
    tsc.to.dt                               html  
    tsc.to.xts                              html  
    weibullProbs                            html  
    xts.to.tsc                              html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 
  'C:/Users/user007/Documents/ttn/R/Projects/dssrip/packages/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'x64'
* removing 'C:/Users/user007/Documents/ttn/R/Projects/dssrip/packages/dssrip'
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package 
  ‘C:/Users/user007/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8UP9Mb/file2d9c5e446300/dssrip_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Java version**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-DSSVue\java\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-DSSVue\java\bin>java -d64
Unrecognized option: -d64
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I tried using the native R (`C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe`) but it did not help either.

Thanks in advance for any pointer!

Comment: Is your Java 64 or 32 bit? It seems to me that you are linking the 64-bit java when installing `rJava`.

Comment: My Java is 32-bit. Thanks!

Comment: I see you set `--no-multiarch` in your `devtools::install_github` call, but not universally. You can configure RStudio to do this globally (ref: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486518-Customizing-Package-Build-Options), perhaps that will work?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: @r2evans: I couldn't find that option in the new RStudio anymore. Maybe they removed it already?

Comment: (1) You must be working on a project in order to get to *Build > Configure Build Tools*; (2) the *"Project build tools"* must be set "Package" in order to see the options for setting "R CMD INSTALL additional options". I have RStudio1.2.1303 and see it there.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! I've just tried that but still encountered the same error `package 'rJava' is not installed for 'arch = x64'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**: [`dssrip`](https://github.com/eheisman/dssrip) has been updated to work with 64-bit [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [java](/questions/tagged/java). You will need a 64-bit compatible version of [HEC-DSSVue](https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-dssvue/downloads.aspx) (e.g., v3.2.3).

**Update**: I had to uninstall and delete everything and started from scratch to make `dssrip` work.

Put the following lines in the `.Rprofile` file:

```
options(dss_jre_location="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HEC\\HEC-DSSVue\\java")
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HEC\\HEC-DSSVue\\java")
```

Install all dependencies:

```
install.packages(c("remotes", "rJava", "data.table", "plyr", "reshape2", "stringr", "tidyverse"),
                 dependencies = TRUE)
```

Note that to force R to install only 32-bit version, I had to use [this syntax](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2057) instead:

```
remotes::install_github("eheisman/dssrip",
                         INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using RStudio -> Tool -> General, then click on "change" button on top that allows you to change the R-Version. A pull-down menu opens where you can select the 32-bit Version and activate it. You will have to restart RStudio to make it happen, though.

Comment: OK, sorry, I did not understand when I read that first though reading it the second time it is clear, that you did that.